# Broadcast Receiver and ContentResolver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-contentresolver

i'm very new to android development and i'm creating an app that receives a sms in a format "get name" name being a contact in the address book and returns a business card to the sender. i've added all the permissions but it seems to crash whenever i send the message "get name". it does work for invalid command though as there is no function call involved

this is my main activity

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {       

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {        
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);                                
         }        
         }
```

this is the broadcast receiver

```
    public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
    String str="",phoneno="";
    MainActivity object=new MainActivity();

    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{

    //---get the SMS message passed in---
    .
    .
    .

    //---retrieve the SMS message received---
    .
    .
    .

        if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("get")){            

            try{

           Intent start_contact_retrieve=new Intent();
           start_contact_retrieve.setClass(context, ContactRetrieve.class); 
           context.startService(start_contact_retrieve); 
           context.stopService(start_contact_retrieve);                               
         }
            catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("receiver function", e.getMessage());
            }

        //---display the new SMS message---
        .
        .
        .

        }       

        else{ 
        SmsManager invalid_command=SmsManager.getDefault();
        invalid_command.sendTextMessage(phoneno, null, "Invalid Command", null, null);
        }         
}   
}
```

and this is the service that i'm calling

```
  public class ContactRetrieve extends Service{

SmsReceiver sreceiver=new SmsReceiver();        
String argument_name=sreceiver.str;
String argument_phoneno=sreceiver.phoneno;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    String returned_data=retrievecontact();
    SmsManager smsman= SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsman.sendTextMessage(argument_phoneno, null, returned_data, null, null);

}

public String retrievecontact(){    
    String phone="No Contact Found";        

    ContentResolver cr=getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);

     if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
             .
             .
             .
             .
   }    

}
     return phone;
} 

}
```

i tried calling this function in the main activity itself but it wouldn't work either. the program just stops responding. i'm stuck with this problem for the past 2 days. any help will be greatly appreciated.
P.S sorry for all the code.

this is the updated code....

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Thread t=new Thread(this);
    t.start();                                            
}


public String retrievecontact(){    

    String phone="No Contact Found";        
            try{
    ContentResolver cr=getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);

     if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {

        .
        .
        .
        }
   }    

}

}


catch(Exception e){
Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
    }
            return phone;
}

public void run() {
    String returned_data=retrievecontact();
    SmsManager smsman= SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsman.sendTextMessage(argument_phoneno, null, returned_data, null, null);
        stopSelf();
}
```

logcat

```
     ??-?? ??:??:??.??? 0       INFO    <unknown>   [ 11-05 14:04:04.204  1571: 1585 E/AndroidRuntime ]
     ??-?? ??:??:??.??? 0       INFO    <unknown>   FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-144
     ??-?? ??:??:??.??? 0       INFO    <unknown>       at android.minor_project.ContactRetrieve.run(ContactRetrieve.java:172)
     ??-?? ??:??:??.??? 0       INFO    <unknown>   [ 11-05 14:04:04.324   190:  291 W/ActivityManager ]
     ??-?? ??:??:??.??? 0       INFO    <unknown>   [ 11-05 14:04:04.343   190:  291 W/WindowManager ]
```

Comment: what's the error.! post your logcat errors.

Comment: whenever i send a message saying "get name" the program shows the message "unfortunately, MainActivity has stopped". the function is being called i.e if i put everything except String phone="No Contact Found"; and return phone in comments, i do get "no contact found" but as soon as the code reached contentresolver, it crashes.

Comment: how many contact you have in the contact book.

Comment: only 2 as of now. i'm running it on emulator

Comment: do you see anything in the logcat about the crash..

Comment: skipped frames, win death, window died, got remote exception sending setActive(false). these occur after i click OK on the error message and not when the error occurs. does anything seem relevant?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to declare a permission in your manifest file to READ_CONTACTS,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to do the following changes:

1) Create a background thread in the service at the `onStartCommand()` method and call `retrievecontact()` from the `run()` method of the thread. Since service also runs in the process man thread (UI thread) it can also crash the app if the content resolver is taking time..

3) Try to put `retrievecontact()` method in try catch to see if it is raising any exception.

4) Remove `context.stopService(start_contact_retrieve);` from the `SMSReciever` class. You should not be stopping the service just after starting it. Instead call `stopSelf()` after following line:

```
SmsManager smsman= SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsman.sendTextMessage(argument_phoneno, null, returned_data, null, null);
```

EDIT 1:

Use the following code to send the name from receiver to the service:

In broadcast reciever:

```
    Intent start_contact_retrieve=new Intent();
start_contact_retrieve.setClass(context, ContactRetrieve.class); 
start_contact_retrieve.putExtra("contact_name", name_of_contact_retrived_from_sms);
context.startService(start_contact_retrieve);
```

In the service:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    String name  = intent.getStringExtra("contact_name");
    //start the thread and pass name as parameter to the retrieve method
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Comment: do you know the point of crash..is it before the while loop or in the while loop..

Comment: crashes at ContentResolver cr=getContentResolver();        there's no error in the logcat

Comment: timeout executing service: serviceRecord...   and a crashing app skipping ANR: processRecord....

Comment: public void run() {
        Thread t=new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }    
or should i call onCreate and or retrievecontact() in the run method

Comment: create the thread in the onCreate() of the service and call the retrievecontact() from its run method()

Comment: seems to have made some progress... i can see the message received toast on the server side now... but shows a fatal exception: thread 126

Comment: there's is no app on the client side... it sends a message and receives a business card. it's working fine...   i've updated my post

Comment: pretty much the same... i've only been able to get the toasts, and that too probably because of the negligible delay introduced by starting a new thread

Comment: do i need to pass intents from mainActivity or something?

Comment: lets break it down into small pieces:
1) SMS receive with get name command. (I am guessing it is working)
2) retrieve user data based on name. is it working?
3) Send the contact in SMS. is it working?

Comment: 1. working
2. code is working if i run it in a separate program in isolation of broadcast receiver.
3. contact in SMS is being sent.. again if i run it in isolation of broadcast receiver i.e if i call the function from MainActivity

Comment: move the thread creation to onStartCommand() method of the Service. How are you passing the name you receive in the SMS to the service?

Comment: i use an object of broadcast receiver class. But i don't think that could be the problem because the problem persists even if i remove the name check....
moved to onStartCommand()... still the same error

Comment: could it be some ide/emulator related problem.. i'm using netbeans

Comment: what is the use of this code MainActivity object=new MainActivity();? you need to use intent extra to send the name from receiver to the service...

Comment: oh that MainActivity object=new MainActivity() is some old code i was using when i was trying to call the method in MainActivity. forgot to delete it.